# Center title on the button image

Tags: ios, swift, button

I want to change button image and title programmatically. When design button image and title (plain) on storyboard it is centered no problem. But  when ı use;

```
  startButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "StartButton"), for: .normal)
  startButton.setAttributedTitle(NSAttributedString(string: "START"), for: .normal)
```

to change button image and title programmatically. Button title not centered on image. It looks like it's on the left of the image.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This may helps you.
use setBackgroundImage instead of setImage

```
startButton.setBackgroundImage(UIImage(named: "StartButton"), for: .normal)
```

hope this solution will solve your problem

Comment: Thanks @Muhammad Nawaz. I also use it but with setTitle not setAttributedTitle. After your answer, I checked again. It solve my problem.